# Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(GraphicsConfiguration gc) always returns insets of main Monitor

Tags: java

Im trying to make a Window that adjusts its size to the screen.
To make it more clear what isn't working i've made this test Code.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    GraphicsEnvironment ge=GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] screenDevices=ge.getScreenDevices();
    for(int i=0;i<screenDevices.length;i++)
    {
        Rectangle2D b=screenDevices[i].getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        Insets insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(screenDevices[i].getDefaultConfiguration());
        System.out.println(screenDevices[i].getIDstring()+": "+insets.bottom);
    }
}
```

[Heres the result of running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmwUC.png)

Comment: Hosted image URLs often become stale and unavailable, breaking future ability to read the post.

Comment: So you have two screen devices and you claim that `insets.bottom` should be different for each device. Do you know what the values should be?

Comment: A quick look at this picture, wich is also linked to in the post, should explain it! 
https://imgur.com/a/gjwOKyg